# tex4ht: entire document is in Helvetica, but tables remain in \rm in the xhmtl output

Tags: tables, tex4ht, helvetica

I am using the following code to change the typeface to Helvetica in the entire document:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This works throughout all environments in the DVI, but not in the xhtml output, where all the tables and their text elements are in `\rm`.  I checked the suspect tables and am not using `\small`, `\scriptsize`, or `\tiny`, after `\begin{table}`, which will reset everything to `\rm`.

Is there a switch setting I need for this, or a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the overall appearance of your document, you need to use CSS. `tex4ht` doesn't keep information about the basic document font. It only saves information about font size, shape or font family when you use font switches like `\itshape`, `\large`, etc.

The following configuration changes the main document font to Helvetica or some of its clones:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{ font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, "Nimbus Sans", Arial, sans-serif;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{section}

test \itshape italic

\begin{tabular}{l}
  hello table
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]